# rollback of addPrimaryKey also drops associated index

Tags: oracle, liquibase

In liquibase 3.5.0 under Oracle 11g, I have added the following changeSet :

```
  <changeSet author="ME" id="PK_CREATION">
    <createIndex tableName="MY_TABLE" indexName="MY_INDEX" unique="true">
      <column name="ID" />
    </createIndex>
    <addPrimaryKey tableName="MY_TABLE" columnNames="ID"
      constraintName="MY_PK" forIndexName="MY_INDEX" />
  </changeSet>
```

The result of the `updateSQL` operation is what I expect :

> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX MY_INDEX ON MY_TABLE(ID);
>
> ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT MY_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID) USING INDEX MY_INDEX;

But the (default) `rollbackSQL` operation drops the index at the same time as the primary key in the first instruction, which causes the second instruction to fail :

> ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE DROP PRIMARY KEY DROP INDEX;
>
> DROP INDEX MY_INDEX;

Is there a way to make it work without specifying a custom rollback operation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the auto-generated SQL for DROP PRIMARY KEY always includes DROP INDEX and has for quite a while. I'm not sure what the original rationale was for always including that but since it's been that way for a while it'll take some research to figure out why it makes sense. I created https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2749 to look into it more as part of the 4.0 changes.

For now, the easiest route is to just add a custom rollback block that just specifies the dropPrimaryKey:

```
<changeSet author="ME" id="PK_CREATION">
    <createIndex tableName="MY_TABLE" indexName="MY_INDEX" unique="true">
        <column name="ID" />
    </createIndex>
    <addPrimaryKey tableName="MY_TABLE" columnNames="ID"
                   constraintName="MY_PK" forIndexName="MY_INDEX" />
    <rollback>
        <dropPrimaryKey tableName="MY_TABLE"/>
    </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

Otherwise, you could also create a custom extension of your own that overrides DropPrimaryKeyGenerator and not include the DROP INDEX portion. See http://liquibase.org/extensions for more information on writing extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Further to [the answer provided by Nathan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37143208/3707762), I suspect [this](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-331) is the original Liquibase bug reported, on which it was decided that generically, dropping of a unique constraint in Oracle is suffixed with the 'DROP INDEX' to drop the underlying index used by the constraint, irrespective of whether the underlying index was created automatically when creating the constraint, or re-used as it had already existed.

This was problematic for me as I had.

1. an already existing unique index named *FOO*.
2. created a unique constraint called *BAR* (with Oracle using the underlying index FOO I had previously created).
3. Used the dropUniqueConstraint tag using Liquibase, which I had expected will only remove *BAR* but also unexpectedly removed *FOO*.